# Importing library to Android project

Tags: android, eclipse

I'm trying to import [this](https://github.com/codinguser/android_contact_picker) library to my Android project. I've done exactly as described in [this link](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html#ReferencingLibraryProject) and doing the usage case 1.

On Logcat I'm getting this:

```
02-15 08:49:09.860: E/AndroidRuntime(6936): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
02-15 08:49:09.860: E/AndroidRuntime(6936): android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.projectname/com.codinguser.android.contactpicker.ContactsPickerActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
02-15 08:49:09.860: E/AndroidRuntime(6936):     at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1405)
...
```

I already tried adding a ContactsPickerActivity activity to the AndroidManifest.xml but I still get the error.

AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          package="com.example.projectname"
          android:versionCode="1"
          android:versionName="1.0" >

    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="10"
              android:targetSdkVersion="17" />

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS" />

    <application android:allowBackup="true"
                 android:icon="@drawable/ic_launcher"
                 android:label="@string/app_name"
                 android:theme="@style/AppTheme" >

        <activity android:name="com.example.projectname.MainActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name"
                  android:uiOptions="splitActionBarWhenNarrow" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name="com.example.projectname.NewTemplateActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
        </activity>

        <provider   android:name="com.example.projectname.DataProvider"
                    android:authorities="com.example.projectname.dataprovider"
                    android:exported="false" >"
        </provider>

        <receiver android:name="com.example.projectname.SentReceiver"
                  android:enabled="true"
                  android:exported="false" >
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="com.example.projectname.MainActivity.SMS_SENT_ACTION" />
            </intent-filter>
        </receiver>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

I do this call:

```
startActivityForResult(new Intent(getActivity(), ContactsPickerActivity.class), GET_PHONE_NUMBER);
```

in a fragment of the MainActivity.

I would appreciate it if someone could guide me as to what I'm doing wrong. Thanks.

Comment: Post your AndroidManifest.xml

Comment: Updated the post with the AndroidManifest.

Comment: You say you added the the required activity entry to your manifest - but I don't see it. (and you do need it)

Comment: I already solved it, but yeah you are right. It was that and also the READ_CONTACTS permission. Thank you.

Comment: When I previously tried adding it, it still didn't work but it was due to not having the permission. I thought that somehow the AndroidManifest.xml of the other project would be imported also but seems like it doesn't work that way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved.

I was missing the following on my AndroidManifest.xml:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_CONTACTS" />

<activity android:name="com.codinguser.android.contactpicker.ContactsPickerActivity"
                  android:label="@string/app_name" >
</activity>
```